# Samsung S3 and 51-android.rules, can not find the device

Tags: samsung-mobile

My 51-android.rules as below, and it can connect with my Samsung i9000 (via DDMS...)

## Samsung i9000

SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="04E8", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"

But not works if using Samsung i9300

Perhaps I lacks the "ATTRS{idProduct}" ?

But I can not find the values for Samsung i9300.

Any comment will help...

THanks *O*

Comment: seems using 'lsusb' to list all usb device can find out as below...

andrew@andrew-desktop:~$ lsusb


**Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04e8:681c Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd** <= i9000, 04e8 as vender id and 681c as product id...

Answer (score 2):

1 `$ sudo apt-get install mtp-tools`

2 connect your Galaxy phone in MTP mode

3 `$ mtp-detect`, then it will output something like below:

> Device 0 (**VID=04e8** and **PID=6860**) is a Samsung
>   GT-P7310/P7510/N7000/I9100/Galaxy Tab 7.7/10.1/S2/Nexus/Note.    Found
>   1 device(s):    Samsung: GT-P7310/P7510/N7000/I9100/Galaxy Tab
>   7.7/10.1/S2/Nexus/Note (04e8:6860) @ bus 1, dev 9

4 Find out the Vendor ID and Product ID. Edit the /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules.

> SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="**04E8**", ATTR{idProduct}=="**6860**",
>   MODE="0666", OWNER="username"

The "username" is the actual username of the user who is authorized to access the phones over USB.

5 `$ sudo service udev restart`

6 re-connect your phone.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have enabled "USB debugging" in the developer options? Try 6860 as product ID.